# I have to add particular row from mysql to a JTable using a button

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, jtable

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventry","root","");
    Statement stemt=con.createStatement();
    String str = "select * from addproducts";
    ResultSet rs = stemt.executeQuery(str);

    while(rs.next())
    {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("pslno"),rs.getString("pid"),rs.getString("pname"),rs.getString("pcategory"),rs.getString("pqty"),rs.getString("ppurcst"),rs.getString("psalprc"),rs.getString("pcmprc"),rs.getString("pdate"),});
    }
  }catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

It is working and display all database table records on `JTable` but,

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventry","root","");
    Statement stemt=con.createStatement();

    String StrQr="";
    if (prid.getText().trim().length()>0 ) {
            StrQr=StrQr + " and pid = " + prid.getText().trim() + " ";
        String str = "select pid, pname,pslno,pcategory,pqty,ppurcst,psalprc,pcmprc from addproducts where 1=1 " + StrQr + " order by pid";
        ResultSet rs = stemt.executeQuery(str);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"connected");

      while(rs.next()) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("pslno"),rs.getString("pid"),rs.getString("pname"),rs.getString("pcategory"),rs.getString("pqty"),rs.getString("ppurcst"),rs.getString("psalprc"),rs.getString("pcmprc"),rs.getString("pdate"),});     
     }
    }                 
  } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        //System.exit(1);
  }
}
```

I want to display particular p_id row on `JTable` but it is not working. No errors occurred.

Comment: Did you SQL work? Are any records returned in the ResultSet? Did you add a System.out.println(..) statement to your code to check if your code is being executed.

Comment: Check the value returned by prid.getText() and verify there is any record available for that pid value in database. Another point, "pdate" is missing in your query string and 1=1 where clause is not required at all.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a concrete answer to your problem but some hints that hopefully will help you to solve it by yourself.

---

#### Avoid performing heavy tasks on the EDT

Beware database calls are time consuming tasks and may block the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) causing the GUI become unresponsive. The EDT is a single and special thread where Swing components creation and update take place. To avoid block this thread consider use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to perform database calls in a background thread and update Swing components in the EDT. See more in [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) trail.

---

#### `DriverManager.getConnection()` is discouraged

According to [the documentations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html), the use of [DiverManager.getConnection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-) is discouraged and should be replaced by [DataSource.getConnection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection--) instead. Using [MySQL JDBC Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) the implementation should look like this:

```
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
dataSource.setDatabaseName("inventry");
dataSource.setPortNumber(3306);
dataSource.setUser("root");
dataSource.setPassword(""); // blank password is a terrible idea

Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

See more in this article: [Connecting with DataSource Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html)

---

#### Don't use `Statement` but `PreparedStatement` instead

If you are going to use JDBC then use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

```
String pid = prid.getText().trim();
...
String sql = "SELECT * FROM addproducts WHERE pid = ?";
PreparedStatemnt ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.getString(1, pid);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

***Note 1:*** Are you sure is a good idea `pid` be a `String`? 
***Note 2:*** To populate your table based on text fields values see [this related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100297/how-to-populate-all-items-in-jtable-when-corresponding-jtextfield-is-empty).

---

#### Suggestion: try-with-resources

Since Java 7 there's a more elegant way to deal with `try-catch` blocks and closeable resources: [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("sql")) {

    statement.setString(1, "pid");

    try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {

        // process ResultSet here

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // Log the exception here
    }

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    // Log the exception here
}
```

Comment: +1  but Connection/PreparedStatement/ResultSet should be close()

Comment: Thanks @mKorbel Yes they should be closed, but that is what `try-with-resources` does. Given Connection/PreparedStatement/ResultSet interfaces extend from [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) introduced in Java 7, there's no need to close this resources manually, they'll be auto-closed when try block finishes either normally or because of an exception.