# Exception Occurred"org.netbeanSecurity:Illegal attempt to exit early?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am working in swing based project.In which i want to open a new window when user log-in successfully but when i click log-in button exception occurred"org.net-bean.ExitSecurityException:Illegal attempt to exit early" i also check my record using print out everything is working well but i have no idea how to fix this problem.Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import org.netbeans.api.settings.ConvertAsProperties;
import org.openide.awt.ActionID;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReference;
import org.openide.windows.TopComponent;
import org.openide.util.NbBundle.Messages;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.openide.util.Exceptions;

class CoreTopComponent extends TopComponent {

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    private String password;
    private String pwd;
    private Component jPasswordField1;
    private Component jButton1;
    //private Object text_password; 

    public CoreTopComponent() {
        initComponents();
        conn = mysqlconnect.ConnecrDb();
    }

    private void ClickActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
        Object password = text_password.getText();
        String sql = "Select * from assistant where pass =?";

        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, text_password.getText());
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are login successfully");
                //setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                org.openide.LifecycleManager.getDefault();
                Login s = new Login();
                s.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are not login successfully");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private void text_passwordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Object password = text_password;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CoreTopComponent core = new CoreTopComponent();
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CoreTopComponent().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton Click;
    private javax.swing.JEditorPane jEditorPane1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JOptionPane jOptionPane1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField text_password;
}
```

And my mysql connection code is here

```
package org.Core.Art;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;  

public class mysqlconnect {
    Connection conn = null;
    public static Connection ConnecrDb() {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auto_lube", "root", "mehar");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection established");
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I visit many site but i can not solve it.Somebody share any link or guide me thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you still having the same problem I've stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25712844/1795530): you are using `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` to connect to a MySQL database. This driver is intended to get a connection using JDBC-ODBC bridge, which is not the case here. Not to mention that was removed in JDK 8: [Removal of JDBC ODBC bridge in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229072/removal-of-jdbc-odbc-bridge-in-java-8/14302647#14302647).

As I've stated you should not use [DriverManager.getConnection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-) but [DataSource.getConnection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection--) instead. So in your `MySqlConnect` class (note [Java Code Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) for class and methods names) make this change:

```
public class MySqlConnect {


    public static Connection connectToDB() {
        try {
            MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
            dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
            dataSource.setDatabaseName("auto_lube");
            dataSource.setPortNumber(3306);
            dataSource.setUser("root");
            dataSource.setPassword("mehar");

            Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection established"); // better log this message
            return conn;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); // better log the exception
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to include the right [MySQL JDBC Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) in your project and stop using `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`

Comment: bundle of thanks please tell me how i can directly contact with you on stack or any other source for sake of more guidance if you want? thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Please give it a try and if it works then [mark this answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). On the other hand it is better if you post questions here instead to contact a single person because: 1) You can be helped by lot of people (not just me). 2) Your questions can help other developers that have similar problems in the future. @SurajAli

Comment: your answer is useful but after using i have same problem why?

Comment: Please edit your question including your updates and **full exception stack trace**. Nobody can guess what is happening now. @SurajAli